# calling main method of another class in main class(Java)

Tags: java

I have 3 classes:

- **Class 1** - Main Class
- **Class 2** - Class used to run Class 3 (having main method).
- **Class 3** - Class that have some logic which is called by a main method in Class 2  and perform one requirement.

Now my requirement is to call class 2 which is already having a main method in my main class.(Main class is super class that will run inclusive of all child classes and child classes having some small requirement in it which needs to run collectively in my main class).

Please suggest how can I do this in java?

Comment: Please provide some code

Comment: You can just call `Otherclass.main()` from wherever

Comment: Have you tried calling Class2.main(...) if yes what error are you facing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, you have a main method in class1, you have a main method in class2, you have some small logic in class3! 
you are doing calculations in class3 and returning the value of those calculations! You are calling that method in class3 in class2 main method and printing it! (because you can't return anything from main), now you want to call the main method of class2 in class1, you just need to type

`Class2.main(args)`

in class1 main method! Make sure that your main method is